# Extra argument 'completionHandler' in call with NSURLSession.sharedSession()

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift, I am trying to make a weather app in IOS using swift,

When I the `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSession.sharedSession()`, I cant run the app its showing this Extra argument 'completionHandler' in call, What may the cause of this error?

my code:

```
 let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecastURL, completionHandler:
        { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void! in
        println(response)
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
```

Comment: Change `Void!` to `Void` should work.

Comment: @gabbler : thanks, it worked, also the `forecastURL` changed to `forecastURL!`

Comment: Good to know it worked,  no `forecastURL` declaration in your code though.

Answer (score 0):

Use *dataTaskWithRequest*.
Here is a sample how i download image

```
        var dowloadTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            // data to image
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            if image != nil {
                // do some stuff
                // preview
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.image = image
                })
            }
        })
        dowloadTask.resume()
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but still showing 'completionHandler'

Comment: completition hanldler is a block, with response data. You can use this data.

Answer (score 0):

```
let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let url = NSURL(string: "")
        let task = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {(location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in
            println("Task completed")

        })
        task.resume()
```